# PHP Replace Last Occurence of a Word in a Multi-Line String

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace the last FROM in an SQL statement that is of multiple lines.

The closest thing that I have to the solution is below as an example.

```
$str = "SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(company.id) FROM company WHERE 1 = 4) as calc_field
        FROM company 
    WHERE id = '09401293481-23-12'";


//preg_match("/(FROM (?!.*FROM))/m", $str, $matches);
//print_r($matches);
$str = preg_replace("/(FROM (?!.*FROM))/m", " REPLACEDFROM ", $str);

echo  $str;
echo "\n\n";
```

However, this does not work. It only works if the string/query is only one line (has no newline characters). The output that I am getting is below.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(company.id)  REPLACEDFROM company WHERE 1 = 4) as calc_field
REPLACEDFROM company
WHERE id = '09401293481-23-12'
```

However, the output that I should be getting, or I would like to get is as seen below.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(company.id) FROM company WHERE 1 = 4) as calc_field
REPLACEDFROM company
WHERE id = '09401293481-23-12'
```

How can I modify my regular expression to get the needed result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\\bFROM\\b(?![\\s\\S]*\\bFROM\\b))/m", " REPLACEDFROM ", $str);
```

Change `.` to `[\s\S]` to match `newlines` as well as `.` be default does not do that.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mG8kZ9/11

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way is to use greedy and the  \K construct.
In addition to being the simplest way, it is the fastest way that it
can be done. Some people don't care about performance.

Just use `(?s).*\K\bFROM\b`

Comment: This works as well. Though, I don't quite understand exactly what it is doing. I will research. Thank You!!